# Printing the two highest values from user input

Tags: java, for-loop, compare

I have an assignment where I have to write a code which lets the user decide an amount of int values to be written in, and then decides what these values should be. There has to be atleast 2 inputs from the user. The program will then compare the values from the input and then print out the two highest values. So far I managed to print out the highest value, but I'm not sure whats wrong with the way I've done it since the output just becomes 0 if I choose to print out 2 numbers and the highest one is entered in first. And I'm also not sure how to keep track of the second highest number either. Would appreciate some help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ToStoersteTall{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("How many numbers? (minimum 2)?:");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            int numbers = reader.nextInt();
            if (numbers >= 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter value #1");
                if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
                    int num1 = reader.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter value #2");
                    if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
                        int num2 = reader.nextInt();

                        int biggest = 0;
                        for (int i = 3; i <= tall; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Enter value #" + i);
                            int num3 = reader.nextInt();
                            biggest = num1;
                            if(biggest < num3){
                                biggest = num3;
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println(biggest);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
                    }                   
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer equal or higher than 2.");
            }   
        } else {
            System.out.print("Vennligst oppgi et heltall større eller lik 2.");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `tall` in the for-loop of the code?

Comment: Where is `tall` declared?

Comment: Sorry, tall is supposed to be numbers. I originally wrote the code with norwegian text and variable names, so could be norwegian text in there which I forgot to translate

Answer (score 1):

> I have an assignment where I have to write a code which lets the user decide an amount of int values to be written in, and then decides what these values should be. There has to be atleast 2 inputs from the user. The program will then compare the values from the input and then print out the two highest values. So far I managed to print out the highest value, but I'm not sure whats wrong with the way I've done it since the output just becomes 0 if I choose to print out 2 numbers and the highest one is entered in first. And I'm also not sure how to keep track of the second highest number either. Would appreciate some help.

A couple things:

- good practice to close scanner (and IO-related resources in general)
- reduced if-statement blocks bloat for easier readability
- you specify 2 guaranteed numbers, so attempt to parse those before looping
- can remove system.exit calls or replace system.exit and move bulk of code back into the larger if-else blocks as originally state in OP (but I refer back to the sake of readability)
- added check for the first and second numbers input to make sure high1 is highest value, and high2 is second highest value.
- keep order while looping and checking values (note: does not use array), if the number is a new high, replace high1 and move high1's value down to high2, or if the number is a second (new) high, replace high2. If values are equal, this logic is excluded and you may want to specify based on your own constraints

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class ToStoersteTall {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("How many numbers? (minimum 2)?:");
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = 0;
      if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
          n = reader.nextInt();
      } else {
          System.out.println("Vennligst oppgi et heltall større eller lik 2.");
          System.exit(-1); // quits execution
      }

      if (n < 2) {
          System.out.println("Please enter an integer equal or higher than 2.");
          System.exit(-2);
      }

      // Since guaranteed 2 numbers, parse and assign now
      int high1 = 0, high2 = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter value # 1");
      if (reader.hasNextInt())
          high1 = reader.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter value # 2");
      if (reader.hasNextInt())
          high2 = reader.nextInt();

      // check to see if a switch to keep correct highest order, swap values if so
      if (high1 < high2) {
          int t = high2;
          high2 = high1;
          high1 = t;
      }

      // loop won't execute if only 2 numbers input, but will if 3 or more specified at start
      for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
          System.out.println("Enter value #" + (i + 1));
          if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
              int t = reader.nextInt();
              if (t > high1) {
                  high2 = high1; // throw away high2 value and replace with high1
                  high1 = t; // replace high1 value with new highest value                    
              } else if (t > high2) {
                  high2 = t;
              }
          } else {
              System.out.println("Please enter an interger");
          }
      }

      reader.close();

      System.out.println("The two highest numbers are: " + high1 + ", " + high2);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: The part where you switched the first and second input if input 1 < input 2 was a good idea. Gonna take note of that. Im not sure what "import java.io.IOException;" is though, I havent learned about that in my course.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also the IOException import was due to me adding in the reader.close(); method call near the end of the main() method. If you haven't learned about exceptions yet, you could simply remove the reader.close() method call, remove the "throws IOException" part of the main method() signature, and remove the "import java.io.IOException" line.

Answer (score 0):

You're already keeping track of the biggest, so why not keep track of the second biggest? Another easy way of solving this problem is to keep all the numbers in a list, sort the list by number size, and grab the two highest entries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and used an array to solve the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static int secondHighest(int... nums) {
        int high1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int high2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int num : nums) {
            if (num > high1) {
                high2 = high1;
                high1 = num;
            } else if (num > high2) {
                high2 = num;
            }
        }
        return high2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many numbers? (minimum 2)?:");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            int numbers = reader.nextInt();
            int[] array = new int[numbers];
            if (numbers >= 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter value #1");
                if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
                    int num1 = reader.nextInt();
                    array[0] = num1;
                    System.out.println("Enter value #2");
                    if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
                        int num2 = reader.nextInt();
                        array[1] = num2;
                        int biggest = 0;
                        for (int i = 3; i <= numbers; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Enter value #" + i);
                            int num3 = reader.nextInt();
                            array[i-1] = num3;
                        }
                        System.out.println("second largest number is" + secondHighest(array));
                        int largest = 0;
                        for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
                            if(array[i] > largest) {
                                largest = array[i];
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Largest number in array is : " +largest);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer equal or higher than 2.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("Vennligst oppgi et heltall større eller lik 2.");
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
How many numbers? (minimum 2)?:
6
Enter value #1
3
Enter value #2
4
Enter value #3
5
Enter value #4
6
Enter value #5
7
Enter value #6
8
second largest number is7
Largest number in array is : 8
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic error in your program. If `numbers` is 2, then the for loop never gets executed, and the value of `biggest` remains zero because it is never updated. Change your declaration of biggest to reflect the current maximum value found so far.

`int biggest = num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;`

That way if the for loop never executes then biggest will be the maximum value of the first two numbers.

As for keeping track of the second highest value, you could introduce another variable `secondBiggest`, initialised in a similar manner to `biggest`, and then write logic to update this value in your for loop. However, in my opinion, it would be much easier to change your strategy to hold the entered values into an array, then when all inputs have been entered, calculate whichever values you desire from the array. This would lead to a much cleaner solution IMO.

(I have assumed that `tall` in the for loop is actually meant to be `numbers`...)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("How many numbers? (minimum 2)?:");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(reader.hasNextInt()){

            int numbers = reader.nextInt();
            if(numbers >= 2){

            int[] list = new int[numbers];

                for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
                    System.out.println("Enter value #" + (i + 1));
                    if(reader.hasNextInt())
                        list[i] = reader.nextInt();
                }//for

                int biggest = 0;
                int secondBiggest = 0;

                // find the values you want
                for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
                    if(list[i] > biggest){
                        secondBiggest = biggest;
                        biggest = list[i];
                    }//if
                    else if(list[i] > secondBiggest)
                      secondBiggest = list[i];
                }//for

                // print your results
                System.out.println("The biggest integer is: " + biggest);
                System.out.println("The second biggest integer is: " + secondBiggest);

            }//if
        }//if
    }//main
}//class
```